# Calculating the total offset in 3D

Tags: math, lua, offset

Okay, this might be harder to explain than to find a solution for it. I'm working on a system to attach elements to another element but I'm looking for a non-RAM killing solution for it. I'm working with Lua 5.0 and I'm unable to include / require any other libraries. But I'll do fine by writing the code myself if I know the correct way to calculate it.

I got a vehicle, the garbage bins ( yes, those weird looking gray/blue things are garbage bins... blame Rockstar for the graphics of GTA San Andreas. ) which are attached to the vehicle indicate the bounding box ( easier to say; this indicates how big the vehicle is. The model is created inside those dustbins and the object fits in there. ). I want people to be able to click somewhere on the trunk of the vehicle which is already working but I'm unsure how to calculate the offset from the center, to where the user has clicked ( the center is where the ped is standing. ).

So lets say we got these coordinates ( might be useful? ):

- Top left: 2753.8962, -2399.3669
- Top right: 2757.0393, -2399.3669
- bottom left: 2753.8962, -2409.8771
- bottom right: 2757.0393, -2409.8771
- center: 2755.4746, -2403.3447

The offsets are as following ( offsets from the center to ... ):

- Top left: -1.578533411026, 3.9779634475708
- Top right: 1.5644228458405, 3.9779634475708
- Bottom left: -1.578533411026, -6.5323362350464
- Bottom right: 1.5644228458405, -6.5323362350464
- Center: 0, 0 ( ofcourse. )

Lets say, a player clicks on the left corner or on the right corner. How will I be able to calculate the total distance from the center, to the locations where the player clicked. I've been trying to mess around to make these positions absolute positions but I didn't see any progress in that and I'm kinda lost right now.

Edit: Also, when I want it to go below the point of zero, it has to convert the number to a negative number.

[image: The image]

Comment: Is the pythagorean theorem not appropriate here? `distance = sqrt((clicked_x-center_x)^2 + (clicked_y-center_y)^2)`?

Comment: I'll try to make it into a working code real quick and come back with the answer.

Comment: That indeed gives me the distance in total, but I'm looking for the offsets for as well as X as Y. Would that just be ( clickedx-centerx)^2 for X and for Y the same thing?

Comment: For offsets, you don't need to square. just `clicked_x - center_x` for X, and the same for Y

Comment: No, fcking, way. I've been trying to do that for over 2 hours but I kept failing. You sir, are a genius. Post it as an answer so I can upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the distance between two points using the Pythagorean theorem:

```
distance = sqrt((clicked_x-center_x)^2 + (clicked_y-center_y)^2)
```

And you can find the X and Y offsets of a point using subtraction.

```
x_offset = clicked_x - center_x
y_offset = clicked_y - center_y
```

Comment: This did work, when the rotation of the element was 0. When I turn the element ( the vehicle ), the offsets aren't calculated correctly anymore. Any easy way to include the rotation in the calculation? Vehicles can be rotated 360 degrees.

Comment: No, nothing easy. It requires some pretty serious trigonometry.

Comment: Just te let you know, I found an easy workaround. I'm forcing vehicles to have a rotation of 0 before they can drop it. :)